# No results displayed in h:dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I have implemented a small application in JSF. When I enter a data in an input field, and I click on the search button, nothing displays in my data table. It should actually return me 2 records in the data table. My methods are correct because I get the 2 records displayed on the console. The managed bean calls the method SearchShowroom from another java class. Note that I also have a POJO class. Please help to figure out the issue.

**Managed Bean**

```
    public List<Showroom> find() throws Exception{
    ShowroomManager sm = new ShowroomManager();
    return sm.SearchShowroom(make1);

}
```

**JSF**

```
<h:form>


    Enter the make of vehicle to search: 
    <h:inputText value = "#{carManagedBean.make1 }"/> <br> <br>

    <h:commandButton value = "Search" action = "#{carManagedBean.find}">

    <br> <br>


    <h:dataTable value = "#{carManagedBean }" var = "car" border = "1" width = "15%">
        <f:facet name = "header">
        <h:outputText value = "List of Showrooms"/>
        </f:facet>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">
                <f:verbatim> Location </f:verbatim>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{car.manager }"/>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name = "header">
                <f:verbatim> Manager </f:verbatim>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value = "#{car.location }"/>

        </h:column>     

    </h:dataTable>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: An `h:datatable` INSIDE a `p:commandButton`???

Comment: Yes.. What's wrong ?

Comment: It is a design I've never ever encountered in my 20 year career

Comment: By the grace of God, you have now encountered bro.

Comment: When does the button trigger? Always? When you click outside the datatable but inside the borders? Does it render at all? Still a weird construction. Please find some basic tutorials...Use a searchengine for that

Answer (score 0):

** Try in this way, as described below ... 
** as value for dataTable you should use a list of objects which you populate with #find() method.
** As additional think you can have a look at richface or primeface showcases to see (dataTable) examples

```
<h:form>
Enter the make of vehicle to search: 
<h:inputText value = "#{carManagedBean.make1 }"/> <br> <br>

<h:commandButton value = "Search" action = "#{carManagedBean.find}" render="yourDataTable">
</h:commandButton>
<br> <br>

<h:dataTable id="yourDataTable" value = "#{carManagedBean.listWithSearchResult }" var = "car" border = "1" width = "15%">
    <f:facet name = "header">
    <h:outputText value = "List of Showrooms"/>
    </f:facet>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name = "header">
            <f:verbatim> Location </f:verbatim>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value = "#{car.manager }"/>
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name = "header">
            <f:verbatim> Manager </f:verbatim>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value = "#{car.location }"/>

    </h:column>     
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this reply. 

The method listWithSearchResult, what it should contain more specifically?

Comment: Search the internet for basic datatable examples. And if you ask this, I now know why you put a datatable IN the commandButton ;-)

Comment: carManagedBean.find method due to your logic make search, the result of this search(car.manager and car.location) you can put in List<Car> listWithSearchResult, which you will use for presenting in dataTable. Better use @Kukelitje sugestion or follow this [mkyong_example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set ajax button like below:

```
<h:commandButton value="Search" actionListener="#{carManagedBean.find}">
 <f:ajax render="myTable"/>
</h:commandButton>

<h:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{carManagedBean}" var="car">
//your code...
</h:dataTable>
```

Don't forget to put an id in your dataTable to redisplay after you click on the button.

PS: If you need to keep in the same page, use "actionListener". The attribute "action" is use just if you need to load other page.